# Auto launch a Chrome web app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, detect, launch

I have a project ongoing that uses a Chrome web app in conjunction with a web page.

There are two scenarios:

1) The user doesn't have the app installed

or

2) The user has it installed but hasn't launched it

**Scenario 1:**

Ideally I'd like to have an install button embedded that will install the app when clicked (not just take the user to the app page where they would have to then click install).

**Scenario 2**

Ideally I'd like the app to auto launch. At worst I'd like the a button, as above, that would launch the already installed app.

Is this something that's doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are. Both require you to verify the app's connection to the site.

For scenario 1, use [inline installation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation). This will still show the install dialog.

For scenario 2, use [external messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).